# make OpenEXR for matlab2017b on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, g++, openexr

it should be simple, but I don't understand why I'm getting this error when I try to compile using

```
g++ -c -DTARGET_API_VERSION=700  -DMX_COMPAT_64  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR  -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/extern/include" -I"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG /home/jaky/MTU/Bos/lf_gen/exrinfo.cpp -o /tmp/mex_157769755466358_1351/exrinfo.o
```

I'm including -I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR and I even can copy the header from the same location(I mean the files are there) yet, the result of the command is just

```
exrinfo.cpp:38:23: fatal error: ImfHeader.h: No such file or directory
#include <ImfHeader.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

I have to mention that just copying ImfHeader.h to the compile place will result in another library request and...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the OpenEXR lib is updated, or at least part of it is updated and it is using gcc 5.x, which is not compatible with the exrinfo.cpp that I was using. I found and updated version of exrinfo.cpp, that fixed the problem.